# Select 1 Col_Name means in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today i found a query like

```
SELECT 1 [Col_name] FROM MyTable
```

and

```
SELECT  [Col_name] FROM MyTable
```

Both seems to return the same result. I am confused.

This is the actual query:

```
SELECT 1 Col1 FROM [Table1] WHERE Col1 = 1 

UNION

SELECT 2 Col1  FROM [Table1]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: When tried your frist query it returns 1 for all records. Second query returns all record values in the column. Third returns 1 in first record and all column record values. [in my example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4131/14) Interesting why you are getting same values for first two queries... But then again I only tested on MySQL...

Comment: This is because someone is using really lazy SQL to define aliases. Should be, IMHO, either `[col_name] = 1` or `1 AS [col_name]` - I think this makes the intention and definition much clearer.

Comment: Yes @AaronBertrand just becuase that guy is not using as i got confused by the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT 1 [Col_name] FROM MyTable
```

will return the literal value `1` with an alias `col_name`. Even if `col_name` is an identifier in your table.

However:

```
SELECT [Col_name] FROM MyTable;
```

will select `col_name` from your table.

The same with:

```
SELECT 1 Col1 FROM [Table1] WHERE Col1 = 1 
UNION
SELECT 2 Col1  FROM [Table1]
```

Will give you only two rows:

```
1
2
```

regardless the values in the table. Because `SELECT 1 Col1 FROM [Table1] WHERE Col1 = 1` returns the literal value `1` with an alias `col1`, `SELECT 2 Col1  FROM [Table1]`  returns the literal value `2` with the same alias `col1` with `UNION`(**Distinct select**) set operator, will give you only two values (1, 2) since they are the only distinct values.

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/86337)

Answer (score 1):

on the actual query, `Col1` are called the alias for the column which has the value of `1`.

if `Col1` is not specified, the column with value given of `1` has no columnName.

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*for more clarification*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6370)